# Is there any Really solution for the issue of "Gradle" , when you start Initializing gradle file in your first app using fultter -Darat

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIC3L.png)[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzy48.png)

> Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
>   Initializing gradle...
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   * Error running Gradle:
>   ProcessException: Process "E:\Android apps\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>   Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom
  > - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar
  >     Required by:
  >      project :
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 15s
  Command: E:\Android apps\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.